# what is the time complexity of this code and max function?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, max, time-complexity, big-o

Give a big-O estimate for the number of operations, where an operation is a comparison or a multiplication,
used in this segment of an algorithm (ignoring comparisons used to test the conditions
in the for loops, where a1, a2, ..., an are positive real numbers). Plus, max function find max value from index 'i' to 'j', not compare just only two value.

```
m := 0
for i := 1 to n
  for j := i + 1 to n
    m := max(ai, aj, m)
```

The problem gives the max function with no description. function get three value, 'ai' is start index, 'aj' is end and 'm' is variable to save max value. I think that the function's time complexity is O(n) because 'A' is just array and we have to travel that section to get a max value. We want to know that code's bigO as well as max function's it.

Comment: hint:two loops and a max.... probably not O(N)

Comment: i added comment to my question. That max function does not compare only two instance. It compares all values between 'i' index and 'j' index then saves the max value at the 'm'. Therefore I think max is O(n). Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all maximum element in an array can be found out without so many iterations through the array. All you need is one pass and setting m to a highly negative number.

```
m := (highly negative number) -inf
for i := 1 to n
    m := max(ai,m)
```

For your algorithm, the time complexity is O(n2) because you travel different sections of the array more than once and not just once as you have mentioned.

To be more precise, time complexity of your algorithm would be :

(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... 1 = n*n - c (some constant)

=> O(n2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what you mean, but what you say is not point i asked. I just wonder that code's time complexity, not a optimal algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: I have answered that also in the second part of my answer.

Comment: I editted the question. The comment plused is that "Plus, max function find max value from index 'i' to 'j', not compare just only two value."